# Orchard CMS - migrate custom content parts

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, hql, orchardcms

I have created my own content part as described here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/[1](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/)

I have also generated migrations as decribed and added an AlterPartDefinition command to migration. Then i have installed my module. After that i can see my own content part in list of all content parts, **but** i can't see fields of my content part. And also i can't use Query filters on fields from my own content part.

Could you please explain what do to get it right?

Here is my migration code:

```
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

    public int Create() {
        // Creating table MapRecord
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MapRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("Latitude", DbType.Double)
            .Column("Longitude", DbType.Double)
        );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(MapPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

        return 1;
    }

    public void Uninstall() {
        // Dropping tables can potentially cause data loss for users so be sure to warn them in your module's documentation about the implications.
        SchemaBuilder.DropTable("MapRecord");
        ContentDefinitionManager.DeletePartDefinition(typeof(MapPart).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't have a driver for your part, am i right? No driver = no part is displayed.

Comment: Look, i have reproduced all things from official tutorial, step by step. Definitely i have created Dirver for my Part. Maybe you don't uderstand what is my problem: created custom part in my module. Installed that module. After that i can attach that part to any content type. I can fill in fields of this part in editor. When i go to Content Definition-> 'Content Parts' tab i can see my custom content part. But when i try to edit it - i don't see any fileds in my custom content part. Also if i go to Quesries-> Filters and try to create filter - there is a name of my content part but no fields.

Comment: It might be a missing Placement.info when fields are missing. Regarding queries, you have to confiugre which fields are queryable first, this can be done in the query menu.